# Use Awk to sum a field using regex and loop

Tags: regex, awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

New to Awk and scripting/programming and asking questions. Hoping to sum a field from a monthly, system generated text file (on Windows10 using WSL1) using Awk. The targeted lines look like this:

```
   Client No.   Client Name                     O/S Balance        Ledger1      Ledger2      Ledger3        Ledger4      Ledger5      Ledger6      Ledger7 Comments
  C00716427.1  Queensview Ohio LLC.              888,924.35           0.00         0.00         0.00     888,924.35     1,803.21         0.00     2,499.96-admin fee
  C00716576.3  0140-8487 Quebec Inc            6,260,987.91           0.00         0.00         0.00   6,260,987.91    18,418.34         0.00        20.99-May 01/20 w/c
  C00716868.1  0328-2400 Quebec Inc.           1,183,948.05           0.00         0.00         0.00   1,183,948.05     2,155.69     5,211.35-1,198,846.32-April 29/20 p/o
  C00617231.3  Ricky Baker Enterprise         49,593,446.91           0.00         0.00         0.00  49,593,446.91    83,220.21   442,202.51-      105.14-May 01/20 w/c
  C00617316.3  101287388 Sarasota LLC.         3,089,599.64           0.00         0.00         0.00   3,089,599.64     2,604.15    27,134.56-        6.08-May 01/20 w/c
  C00617447.2  AmeriUnion Trade 123            6,088,229.78           0.00         0.00         0.00   6,088,229.78    24,921.06         0.00       325.26-surplus funds
```

I would like the output to be only the values of Client No. and Ledger7 (no need for the headers). By piecing together some other solutions, this is what I've mashed together:

```
awk '/C00/ {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub ( ",","" ); if($i ~ /[0-9]\-[a-zA-Z]/){print substr($1,4,8) " " $i} } }' April.txt
```

Which produces:

```
716427.1 2499.96-admin
716576.3 20.99-May
716868.1 5211.35-1198846.32-April
617231.3 105.14-May
617316.3 6.08-May
617447.2 325.26-surplus
```

FYI - there is always a "-" separating Ledger7 and the comments. The issue for me occurs when Ledger6 is a negative value and Ledger7 is >= $1 million.

Desired output to achieve the sum of `1201803.75`:

```
716427.1 2499.96
716576.3 20.99
716868.1 1198846.32
617231.3 105.14
617316.3 6.08
617447.2 325.26
```

Any ideas on how to adapt or restructure my script? Let me know if further details are needed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu awk`, you may can do this:

```sh
awk 'NR>1 {
   amt = gensub(/^.*[-[:blank:]]([0-9][0-9,.]*)-[^-]+$/, "\\1", 1)
   gsub(/,/, "", amt)
   print $1, amt
}' file
```

```
C00716427.1 2499.96
C00716576.3 20.99
C00716868.1 1198846.32
C00617231.3 105.14
C00617316.3 6.08
C00617447.2 325.26
```

**How it works:**

- `NR > 1` ignore header row
- `gensub` function matches and captures last amount file that comes after a space or hyphen and is followed by a hyphen.
- `gsub` function removes all commas from amount field
- `print` simply prints 1st column with amount

Comment: success! Thanks very much, kind sir. For anyone else trying to run this on the command line instead of an awk file, be sure to add ";" (semi-colons) where needed.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Written and tested in link https://ideone.com/3oYBGq

```
awk '
match($0,/[-[:blank:]]([0-9][0-9,.]*)-[^-]+$/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/^ +/,"",val)
  sub(/ +.*$/,"",val)
  num=split(val,arr,"-")
  print $1,arr[num-1]
  val=""
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[-[:blank:]]([0-9][0-9,.]*)-[^-]+$/){      ##Using match function to match regex [-[:blank:]]([0-9][0-9,.]*)-[^-]+ till end of line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                      ##Creating val which has substring of matched regex value in current line as shown above.
  sub(/^ +/,"",val)                                  ##Substituting starting space with NULL in val here.
  sub(/ +.*$/,"",val)                                ##Substituting space till everything in last of line in val here.
  num=split(val,arr,"-")                             ##Splitting val value into array arr with delimoter - here.
  print $1,arr[num-1]                                ##Printing 1st field and 2nd last value of arr here.
  val=""                                             ##Nullify val here.
}' Input_file                                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @RavinderSingh13 and detailed breakdown.This almost did the trick. I don't believe I can easily sum field $2 as the commas remain. I attempted to remove them with additional sub function: `sub(/,/,"",val)`. But the second comma remained in row 3.